# Website is really slow and not sure what is slowing it down

Tags: javascript, magento, themes, megamenu

My site:  http://www.acuity-sports.com/

After abut 20-30 seconds after a page loads all of the mouseovers start to lag really bad.     I've been trying to kill what I think is an overkill of JS.  Could it be the server that is causing this or is it from the code?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Debug and profile your code to find out.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an appropriate question for SO. I just tested your site in http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140321_8E_1FV/. May be the report will help.

Comment: Google page speed [analysis](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&utm_source=wmx&utm_campaign=wmx_otherlinks) might help

Comment: You are loading about 40 separate javascript files, and over 20 .css files - so - that's how magento or whatever that is roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect your site to be that fast when it is loading over 40 stylesheets and jqueries. I'm actually very surprised they are not conflicting with each other. Not to mention you must have a million css elements that are probably running duplicated.

I am the senior developer for the Pennsylvania State Welfare Website, A government website and I run it off two css declarations (minified) and maybe 6 css files in the root directory.

You have to shrink that up man. You really don't need all that. Once you load a theme you are already gaining a lot of unnecessary code, then you start adding as many widgets as you can making it even worse. Big no-no. If you wan to add something, build it yourself as small as possible and add it to your solution. Not only you will become a developer in time, but your site will run only needed code.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I've been trying to clean up this theme that our company wanted to use.  I'm trying to strip it down because its so bloated.  Way to much going on that I cannot clean up in the admin panel of magento.

Answer (score 1):

Use a firefox plugin like firebug or yslow while browsing your website.  You will see server load times in the network traffic panel